# Website with possible closed forms of numbers

Tags: reference-request, closed-form, online-resources

I encountered a website that had a large number of possible closed forms per a user number entry. It is not WA. I cannot locate it now. I had it saved before having to reinstall my browser. Anyone know of the site?

It is not OEIS. The site collects just single number entries, not   sequences.

If I am curious if there's a closed form for a [truncated decimal representation of a] number such as 0.124578098472362 I would simply enter it and I'd see a list of possible closed forms for the number.

Comment: What does "closed forms per a user number entry" mean more precisely? Yet maybe you mean OEIS. https://oeis.org/

Comment: Or maybe Plouffe's inverter, now offline and replaced by https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/

Comment: Yes, thank you. I see the site you mentioned and it's almost the same - seems the screen a bit different as I was able to scroll through a different window before yet this dump of numbers will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

As jca recognized in a comment, this is the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/).

---

Back in 2013, this site had a [community ad for ISC](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9931/), but nobody proposed such an ad for 2014 or 2015.

Comment: Why the -2? Is someone from OEIS stalking me?

http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html

Is what I am looking for. This could be helpful to know by others as well.